# HoW count sequences in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a series like below. The series is a dataframe. I convert to a series just to show here.

```
Responses = {N, N, N, N, N, S, N, N, N, N, N, N, S, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, S, S, S, S, S, S, N, N, S, N, N, N, S, S, S, S, N, S, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, S, S, N, N, N, S, S, S, N, S, S, S, S, S, S, S, S,N, N, N, N, N, S, N, N, N, N, N, N, S, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, S, S, S, S, S, S, N, N, S, N, N, N, S, S, S, S, N, S, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, S, S, N, N, N, S, S, S, N, S, S, S, S, S, S, S, S }
```

I use this code to count the largest sequence of 'S' (I know that this is not the best way):

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\teste\\pergunta.csv')

count = 0
prev = 0
indexend = 0
indexcount = 0
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if df['Responses'].loc[i] == 'S':
        count += 1
        indexcount = i
    else:
        if count > prev:
            prev = count
            indexend = i
        count = 0

if count > prev:
    prev = count
    indexend = indexcount

print("The longest sequence is "+str(prev))
count = 0
prev = 0
indexend = 0
indexcount = 0
```

The code says that the longest sequence os 'S' is 8. This is ok.

But, this sequence of 8 S happens twice.

My question: I need a code that counts individual sequences of S from the longest to the minimum.

Something like:

| Sequence | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 2 times |
| 7 | 1 times |
| 6 | 3 times |
| 5 | 1 times |
| 4 | x times |
| 3 | x times |
| 2 | x times |

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
s = pd.Series(Responses)
s = s.loc[s.eq('S')].groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).count().value_counts()
df = s.map('{} times'.format).rename_axis('Sequence').reset_index(name = 'Frequency')
```

Output:

```
   Sequence Frequency
0         1   8 times
1         6   2 times
2         4   2 times
3         2   2 times
4         3   2 times
5         8   2 times
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby


out = {}
for k, g in groupby(Responses):
    if k == 'S':
        l = sum(1 for _ in g)
        out[l] = out.get(l, 0) + 1

df = pd.DataFrame([{'Sequence': k, 'Frequency': f'{v} times'} for k, v in out.items()]).sort_values('Sequence', ascending=False)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Sequence Frequency
5         8   2 times
1         6   2 times
2         4   2 times
4         3   2 times
3         2   2 times
0         1   8 times
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools` :

```py
import itertools as it
import pandas as pd

N='N'
S='S'
df = pd.DataFrame({'Responses':[N, N, N, N, N, S, N, N, N, N, N, N, S, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, S, S, S, S, S, S, N, N, S, N, N, N, S, S, S, S, N, S, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, S, S, N, N, N, S, S, S, N, S, S, S, S, S, S, S, S,N, N, N, N, N, S, N, N, N, N, N, N, S, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, S, S, S, S, S, S, N, N, S, N, N, N, S, S, S, S, N, S, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, S, S, N, N, N, S, S, S, N, S, S, S, S, S, S, S, S] })

l = [list(g).count('S') for k, g in it.groupby(df['Responses']) if k=='S']

r = (pd.DataFrame.from_dict({i:l.count(i) for i in range(min(l), max(l)+1)}, 
                            orient='index')
                 .reset_index()
                 )

r.columns=['Sequence', 'Frequency']

print(r)
```

```
   Sequence  Frequency
0         1          8
1         2          2
2         3          2
3         4          2
4         5          0
5         6          2
6         7          0
7         8          2
```